# Can't migrate Django DB via Vagrantfile

Tags: python, django, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm having an issue trying to get a command-line django command to run during `vagrant up`. I've made sure that the path is correct, and that it's being executed from the proper location on the Vagrant dev box. However, I keep getting the same error shown below.

[image: error-message]

Below is my Vagrantfile (the relevant parts, at least).

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define :devbox do |b|
    b.vm.box = "precise64"
    b.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"
    ...
    b.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "sudo cf-agent -KI"
    b.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "echo 'Running the syncdb now'"
    b.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "source ~/.bashrc && cd / && /devbox/barista/manage.py syncdb --noinput --settings=test_app.settings.dev"
  end
end
```

Am I missing something in regards to running command line commands with Django on a Vagrant box? I'm simply just trying to run the `manage.py syncdb` command. I'm wondering if there's a path or bash issue that I'm not aware of.

I am currently running Django 1.4.2.

Comment: What version of Django are you running? `syncdb` was deprecated in 1.7 and has been removed competely in the latest dev version.

Comment: Sorry, I neglected to mention that. Currently running Django 1.4.2.

Comment: can you output your settings file. did you try to start the vm without this provisioner and run the same command directly from the vm ? does it work ?

Comment: yep, if you place the inline command in the VM, it works as expected.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri did you have any additional insights if the command  works when run in the VM command line?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably a privileged issue, if you run the shell provision (or any provisioner block) like this, it will run as sudo but you just probably want to run as normal (vagrant) user, so you can add `privileged: "false"`

```
b.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "source ~/.bashrc && cd / && /devbox/barista/manage.py syncdb --noinput --settings=test_app.settings.dev", privileged: "false"
```

also for this one, you do not need to explicitly mention sudo as it'll be done automatically for you

```
b.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "sudo cf-agent -KI"
```

hence your Vagrantfile would be something like

```
b.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "cf-agent -KI"
b.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "echo 'Running the syncdb now'"
b.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "source ~/.bashrc && cd / && /devbox/barista/manage.py syncdb --noinput --settings=test_app.settings.dev", :privileged => "false"
```